# How to render <Image /> on React Native on android API 29+

Tags: android, react-native, mediastore

The issue I have is that since android api version 29+, Android doesn't allow you to read media file with `file:///path/to/the/file.jpg` so when I try to render images from gallery, I can't render it in the JS side using  component from `react-native` because I can't use `uri`. Has anyone figured out way to work around?

**Edit**
Here I am trying to render image that is stored in the device and using content resolver with MediaStore Api.

Comment: You found anything?

Answer (score 0):

a simple solution is that, make a separate folder and add you all pics in and can simply import it. I am importing images in my project as

[image]

```
    <Image
              style={{width: 66, height: 58}}
              source={require('../assets/truck1.png')} 
/>
```

Comment: Here I am trying to render image that is stored in the device and using content resolver with MediaStore Api.